# Center mega menu in middle of navitem

Tags: css, bulma

So I have the below code that will render a mega menu for me using the `Bulma Framework`, but I'm running into issues on having it position center underneath.

**Please note: Please click "Run code" and then expand to full page to see what I mean, the mobile version doesn't show it**.

The code that I have renders the mega menus as such:
[image]

I want to have the hoverable menu item be centered with the mega menu (Meaning have the middle "Sub Menu Title" be right below the blog hover dropdown.

- There is a `min-width: 50%` set on the `.navbar-dropdown` class.

All help would be appreciated.

```css
.navbar-item.is-mega {
  position: static;

  .is-mega-menu-title {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: .375rem 1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.9.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-brand">
    <a class="navbar-item" href="http://bulma.io">
      <img src="http://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png" alt="Bulma: a modern CSS framework based on Flexbox" width="112" height="28">
    </a>
    <div class="navbar-burger burger" data-target="navMenubd-example">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="navMenubd-example" class="navbar-menu">
    <div class="navbar-start">
  <a class="navbar-item">
    Home1
  </a>
  <a class="navbar-item">
    Home2
  </a>
  <a class="navbar-item">
    Home3
  </a>
  <a class="navbar-item">
    Home3
  </a>
  <a class="navbar-item">
    Home3
  </a>
  <a class="navbar-item">
    Home3
  </a>
      <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable is-mega">
        <div class="navbar-link flex">
          Blog <span class="tag is-info ml-2">Hover here<span>
        </div>
        <div id="blogDropdown" class="navbar-dropdown " style="min-width: 50%" data-style="width: 18rem;">
          <div class="container is-fluid">
            <div class="columns">
              <div class="column">
                <h1 class="title is-6 is-mega-menu-title">Sub Menu Title</h1>
                <a class="navbar-item" href="/2017/08/03/list-of-tags/">
                  <div class="navbar-content">
                    <p>
                      <small class="has-text-info">03 Aug 2017</small>
                    </p>
                    <p>New feature: list of tags</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item" href="/2017/08/03/list-of-tags/">
                  <div class="navbar-content">
                    <p>
                      <small class="has-text-info">03 Aug 2017</small>
                    </p>
                    <p>New feature: list of tags</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item" href="/2017/08/03/list-of-tags/">
                  <div class="navbar-content">
                    <p>
                      <small class="has-text-info">03 Aug 2017</small>
                    </p>
                    <p>New feature: list of tags</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                <h1 class="title is-6 is-mega-menu-title">Sub Menu Title</h1>
                <a class="navbar-item" href="/2017/08/03/list-of-tags/">
                  <div class="navbar-content">

                    <p>
                      <small class="has-text-info">03 Aug 2017</small>
                    </p>
                    <p>New feature: list of tags</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item " href="/documentation/overview/start/">
                  Overview
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/documentation/modifiers/syntax/">
                  Modifiers
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/documentation/columns/basics/">
                  Columns
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                <h1 class="title is-6 is-mega-menu-title">Sub Menu Title</h1>
                <a class="navbar-item " href="/documentation/overview/start/">
                  Overview
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/documentation/modifiers/syntax/">
                  Modifiers
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/documentation/columns/basics/">
                  Columns
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/documentation/layout/container/">
                  Layout
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <hr class="navbar-divider">
          <div class="navbar-item">
            <div class="navbar-content">
              <div class="level is-mobile">
                <div class="level-left">
                  <div class="level-item">
                    <strong>Stay up to date!</strong>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="level-right">
                  <div class="level-item">
                    <a class="button bd-is-rss is-small" href="http://bulma.io/atom.xml">
                      <span class="icon is-small">
                        <i class="fa fa-rss"></i>
                      </span>
                      <span>Subscribe</span>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  <a class="navbar-item">
    Home
  </a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-end">
      <a class="navbar-item is-hidden-desktop-only" href="https://github.com/jgthms/bulma" target="_blank">
        <span class="icon" style="color: #333;">
          <i class="fa fa-github"></i>
        </span>
      </a>
      <a class="navbar-item is-hidden-desktop-only" href="https://twitter.com/jgthms" target="_blank">
        <span class="icon" style="color: #55acee;">
          <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
        </span>
      </a>
      <div class="navbar-item">
        <div class="field is-grouped">
          <p class="control">
            <a class="bd-tw-button button" data-social-network="Twitter" data-social-action="tweet" data-social-target="http://bulma.io" target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Bulma: a modern CSS framework based on Flexbox&hashtags=bulmaio&url=http://bulma.io&via=jgthms">
              <span class="icon">
                <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
              </span>
              <span>
                Tweet
              </span>
            </a>

          </p>
          <p class="control">
            <a class="button is-primary" href="https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/archive/0.5.1.zip">
              <span class="icon">
                <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
              </span>
              <span>Download</span>
            </a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently in bulma.min.css `.navbar-dropdown` has:

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
```

Thus you could add those 2 lines to do the trick:

```
left: 50%; // will position it at 50% of its relative parent (the .navbar)
transform: translateX(-50%); // will translate it 50% of its own width to the left
```

Comment: Happy to help !